# I can't connect to sql server via asp.net from android

Tags: android, sql, asp.net, sql-server, ksoap2

I'm using ksoap2 libs in my apps.

There are 3 webmethod in my asp.net file.
1 methods is sql server query, the rests are kinds of helloWorld, adding two numbers.

I checked my asp worked properly in vs 2012. 3 methods worked well.
Problem is that when running my android app, 2 methods are working properly.
but the method with sql server is always throwing errors:

> 05-25 13:35:46.630 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:
>   SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable
>   to process request. ---> A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Access is denied.) ---> Access is
>   denied' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@241d2389 05-25
>   13:35:46.630 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:     at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:137)
>   05-25 13:35:46.630 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:
>   at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140) 05-25
>   13:35:46.630 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:     at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:129) 05-25
>   13:35:46.630 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:     at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.parseResponse(HttpTransportSE.java:301)
>   05-25 13:35:46.630 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:
>   at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:274)
>   05-25 13:35:46.660 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:
>   at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
>   05-25 13:35:46.660 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:
>   at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
>   05-25 13:35:46.670 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.example.bruce.xmlwork.MainActivity.readData(MainActivity.java:156)
>   05-25 13:35:46.690 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.example.bruce.xmlwork.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:101)
>   05-25 13:35:46.690 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.example.bruce.xmlwork.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:89)
>   05-25 13:35:46.690 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 05-25 13:35:46.690
>   8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 05-25
>   13:35:46.690 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 05-25
>   13:35:46.690 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   05-25 13:35:46.690 8269-8478/com.example.bruce.xmlwork W/System.err:
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)

```
protected String readData(){
    Log.d("ddd","readData");
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);  //error occours
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "no";
}
```

How could I solve this.. Please Help me.

----added-----
in asp.net

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string returnName()
    {
        String strSql = "SELECT * from address";
        SqlConnection objCon = new SqlConnection();
        objCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=192.168.13.79,1433;Initial Catalog=bruceBasic;User ID=sa;Password=***";
        objCon.Open();
        SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand();
        objCmd.Connection = objCon;
        objCmd.CommandText = strSql;
        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = objCmd;
        DataSet tempDs = new DataSet("TEMP");
        adapter.Fill(tempDs);

        objCon.Close();


        return tempDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["addr_city"].ToString();
    }
```

And I allowed remote connection in DB properies.

Comment: Do you mean it only doesn't work when calling it from `android`? You should show us how you define your database connection. Because you get **Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections: Access is denied**

Comment: check the data source/Server specified in you Database connection string. Also make sure the Sql Server is accessible remotely.

Comment: data source/server details are correct. I've checked and checked.

Comment: to J.Chomel       Yes.Only calling sql-webmethod in asp from android is not  working .